# Create permission to see view results without permission to access tables behind it

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a view in MSSQL2008 that provides some specific details from system tables, as the users of this view don't have access to the system tables themselves. Is there a way to give provide permission for them to see that data via the view but not access it directly from the table? Like giving the view a specific user to execute under regardless of who is calling the view (providing that user has permission to select from the view).

I've found permissions to select from the view, select from the table, but not the in-between that I'm looking for.

Comment: Might have to do with the user not having access to the sys schema? Is there a way to give them permission to the schema without giving them permission to perform any direct actions in that schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned (in my deleted comment), provided that the 2 objects, in this case the `TABLE` and `VIEW`, have the same owner then a `USER` using the object can make use of ownership chaining. So if the `USER` has access to `SELECT` from the `VIEW` but not the `TABLE`,  when they query the `VIEW` they will be given implicit permission to be able to query the table, as they are owned by the same user.

This chaining can continue on afterwards. For example, a `PROCEDURE` that references a `VIEW`, that references 3 `TABLE`s and then `INSERT`s into a 4th. The `USER` might only have access to use the `PROCEDURE`, but if all the objects are owned by the same `USER`, then the permissions will be implicitly given to both `SELECT` and `INSERT` within the context of the `PROCEDURE`.

This is explained in more detail in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-ownership-chains-and-context-switching?view=sql-server-ver15).

As a simple example, see the below, where the user `SomeUser` successfully manages to `SELECT` from the `VIEW`, despite the explicit `DENY` on the underlying table. In this case, on my instance, both objects are owned by the `dbo` user:

```sql
--Create table
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (SomeID int IDENTITY,
                            SomeDate datetime DEFAULT GETDATE());
GO
--Some Rows
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable
DEFAULT VALUES;
GO 25
--Create view
CREATE VIEW dbo.SomeView AS
    SELECT SomeDate
    FROM dbo.SomeTable;
GO
--See Owners
SELECT o.[name] AS ObjectName, dp.[name] AS OwningUser
FROM sys.objects o
     JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
     JOIN sys.database_principals dp ON o.principal_id = dp.principal_id
                                     OR (o.principal_id IS NULL AND s.principal_id = dp.principal_id)
WHERE o.[name] IN (N'SomeTable','SomeView');
GO
--Create User
CREATE USER SomeUser WITHOUT LOGIN;
GO
--Grant SELECT on View, DENY on Table
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.SomeView TO SomeUser;
DENY SELECT ON dbo.SomeTable TO SomeUser;
GO
--Switch User Context
EXECUTE AS USER = 'SomeUser';
GO
--Run Select
SELECT *
FROM dbo.SomeView;
GO
--Revert context
REVERT
GO
--Clean up
DROP USER SomeUser;
DROP VIEW dbo.SomeView;
DROP TABLE dbo.SomeTable;
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I tried your example, and as written it works. However if you change the view to select from the sys schema as I mentioned in my post it stops working. For example:


CREATE VIEW dbo.SomeView AS
select t.name as TableName, i.last_user_update as LastRefresh
from sys.tables t
left join sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats i on i.object_id = t.object_id
where t.name in ('SomeTable')

Comment: objects on `sys` aren't owned by the same user, @David . They're permissions are controlled completely separately I am afraid. You could create a procedure with an `EXECUTE AS` clause, or sign it [with a certificate] that has access to the `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` system view, but you wouldn't be able to do this in a `VIEW`.